# TAdoCommand не видит временную таблицу

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки. Вот такой вопрос. Есть код:

```
MyAdoConnection.BeginTrans;
MyAdoCommand1.Execute;
MyAdoCommand2.Execute;
MyAdoConnection.CommitTrans;
```

В первой команде MyAdoCommand1 создается временная таблица #temp, в MyAdoCommand2 происходят операции с этой таблицей. При выполнении вылетает исключение в MyAdoCommand2: "Не найдена таблица #temp". Если ручками убрать MyAdoConnection.BeginTrans и MyAdoConnection.CommitTrans, то всё работает успешно, а мне транзакция нужна. Заранее благодарю за ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Если речь об MS SQL, то обратите внимание, что временная таблица создается в системных базах данных в базе tempdb, правильно ли Вы к ней обращаетесь? Судя по ошибке Вы вводите только имя таблицы... Попробуйте tempdb.#temp